# What are best practices for abstracting and helper methods within a View Controller when creating the UI programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, oop

I'm starting to get overwhelmed with how many helper methods I'm adding to each View Controller. Is there anything I could do in addition to making a separate Factory class to handle the creation of the UI elements to keep my code clean?

Here's an idea of some helper methods I end up using on each view controller:

`addBackground` `addLogo` `addLoginTableView` `createTextFields` `addDefaultTextFields` `addAdditionalTextField` `styleUITextField` `setButtonBlue` `setButtonClear` `textFieldFactory:inRect:` `buttonFactoryWithImage:withSel:inRect:` `buttonFactoryWithoutImage:withSel:inRect:` `buttonPressed` `updateEventLabels`

The other big issue is I've ended up with a bunch of global variables to use when making an element's frame. Things like `windowWidth` `windowHeight` `buttonWidth` `buttonHeight` `buttonHorizontalPadding` `specificButtonVerticalPadding`. I know global variables aren't the best, but it's better than hard coding for each element.

The last issue would be adding animations to specific elements. Something like a `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` or setting the frame off screen and then animating it to it's intended position - for a swipe-from type effect.

I've tried to google around and find what other people are doing but to no luck, so any input or resources is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think about extensions (swift) or cattegories (objC). You could save and reuse a bunch of code. After this, subclass everything you cant (oo patterns).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about categories. They look perfect for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: http://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/lighter-view-controllers/ it maybe helps you too

Comment: Very helpful. Now there's quite a lot of refactoring to do.

Comment: So I'm using factories, moving the delegate and data source methods out, and it's much cleaner than before. I'm going to make my next VC with a UIView before refactoring the old ones. The one thing I'm left with is all the global variables I'm using for position and sizes. Could auto layout resolve this or is it just as bad?

Comment: Try to forget "manual layout". Do it is dificult to create and maintain. Usu autolayout in everything: less code, organization, universal devices, etc..

Comment: Alright, I'll have to give it a try on the UIView VC after refactoring everything . Thanks a bunch!